# Radio Button listener on animation ends

Tags: android

I need to know when animation ends if  user select a RadioButton from a Radiogroup.

My Case: 
I have a viewPager with questions when user answers at my question then move to the next position (question).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2GZL.png)

Sample code:

```
 @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
    viewPagerHelper.goToNext();
    Log.e("CardAdapter", "Text :" + checkedRadioButton.getText());
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your case, have you tried something like this ?

**Edit** : If you add an animation listener ? not works, throw a NullPointer on `getAnimation()`

```
RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) _view.findViewById(R.id.rg);
myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.rb1 : // do something 
                break;
            case R.id.rb2 : // do something else
                break;
        }
    }
});

myRadioGroup.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // crossing fingers
        goToNextQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

**Edit2** : SHITTY solution ! DO NOT do this at home please

I'm not proud of it, but it's works with this solution

```
myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

250 milliseconds are purely estimated.

I hope that will help you

Comment: with this code user will never see the animation of Radiogroup

Comment: mmh ok, I see what you want

Comment: @Cliff I propose to you something else

Comment: let me check it :)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.cliff.apodeixoulis, PID: 17306
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.animation.Animation.setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation$AnimationListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Mmmh ok, that normal, if we didn't init animation object, I'm looking for something else :)